# Use a prop element of type RouteComponentProps in react redux using Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-redux, react-router-dom

I have a Component with the following props:

```js
interface LocationBoxProps {
    location: Location | null
    workshift: Workshift
}
```

The interface cannot extend RouteComponentProps because it already have a **location** field and to obtain a cleaner interface I would like to create a field of type RouteComponentProps. Something like this:

```js
interface LocationBoxProps {
    location: Location | null
    workshift: Workshift
    routeProps: RouteComponentProps // <- new field
}
```

however I don't know how to map this new field (routeProps) in the mapStateToProps method. I treid

```js
const mapStateToProps = (store: RootState, ownProps: LocationBoxProps) => {
    return{
        location: store.work.location,
        workshift: store.work.workshift,

        routeProps: ownProps.routeProps
    }
}
```

but when I try to do this.props.routeProps.history.push('/something') I get the error

```js
Cannot read property 'history' of undefined
```

How can I map correctly routeProps in mapStateToProps?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confusing which props are coming from redux and which are coming from react-router-dom.  Mapping `routeProps: ownProps.routeProps` does nothing because you're expecting the props to already be present under the key `routeProps` and then assigning them back to the same key.

Do you need to use `location` from the router, or just the `history`? If all you need is the history then get rid of all of this stuff about `routeProps` and just access `this.props.history.push('/something')`.

If you're concerned about naming collisions, you can access the history and location using [hooks](https://reactrouter.com/core/api/Hooks/uselocation) so that you can name them whatever you want.  The hooks also make things easier for typescript to understand because `Route` injects props in a way that is somewhat hidden.